# Read template with nested loops by regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a template structure, which resembles that of Twig. I divide this currently successful with regex.

```
{% for array as item %}
    {% item.party %}
    {% item %}
{% else %}
    // If empty...
{% endfor %}

{% if !var %}
   // Full
{% else %}
   // Empty
{% endif %}

// Is var full, replace block whit var
{% block var %}
   Some Code
{% endblock %}
```

Regex
    `preg_match_all('/(?:{% (for|if|block) )(.*?)(?: %})(.*?)({% else %}(.*?))?(?:{% end\1 %})/is', $content, $data);`

Now I would like that can also nest. The only problem is that the loop always take the wrong end. The outer loop takes the inner end because it is first.

```
{% for array as item %} // From here on
   {% item.title %}
   {% for item.sub as sub %}
      {% sub.title %}
   {% endfor %} // To here
{% endfor %}
```

Do you know how I get the regex to choose the right end? On the content of the first level, I can also re-apply the entire function. But it must be the regex to use the correct end.

Comment: This can be done with `(?R)` and friends. But you are better off parsing this in code instead of regex. Use regex as a lexer to tokenize the input, then parse the tokens with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to meet your requirements.

It uses `(?R)` to allow recursive matching of the whole expression within a block.
See [Recursive patterns](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.recursive.php)
 and [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt).

```
preg_match_all(
    '/(?:{% (for|if|block) )(.*?)(?: %})(?:(?R)|(.*?)({% else %}(.*?))?)*(?:{% end\1 %})/is',
     $content, $data
);
```

The only changes I made to your expression were additions to surround the block's inner content sub-pattern in a non-capturing group, and to add the `(R)` alternative to it:

```
start(?:(?R)|inner)end
```

The `(?R)` attempts to match the whole regular expression, thereby matching any other blocks within the outer block.

You could also surround the `(?R)` with parentheses, i.e. `((?R))`, so these inner blocks will be available in the third capture group.